# XML not working with php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I made a code in php. I want a XML output in browser but it shows error. Actually it works fine in locally. But when i hosted it shows error as "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element".

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: text/xml");
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
 echo '<group>';
 echo '<family>';
 echo '<person>';
 echo 'first name';
 echo '</person>';
 echo '</family>';
 echo '</group>';
?>
```

plese help me.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `die();` after `echo '</group>';`.

If that clears up your error, then something is being output after the code you posted.

Alternatively you could prepare your XML like:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<group>
    <family>
        <person>first name</person>
    </family>
</group>
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it allowed you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a white-space before your <\?php so before <\?xml

It is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your script itself works fine in my local environment.
The problem probably comes from somewhere else.

You may have something outputed **after** your script.

And it is not a white-space before php cause otherwise you would have an error similar to :
**XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document**